# Can I inhibit class/function inclusion in a "truly lazy" SWIG interface file?

Tags: c++, swig

I have successfully wrapped a C++ library for C# using the "truly lazy" approach from the [SWIG tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html). It looks like this:

```
%module example
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
%}

/* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
%include "header1.h"
%include "header2.h"
```

However, this includes one or two methods and classes I don't want. Can I inhibit the inclusion of a class and/or method after a `%include`? Something like adding:

```
%ignore Math.functionNotToInclude(int x, int y);
```

Comment: you can add some special preprocessor (or use SWIG provided) defines and use them in ifdefs in headers (like `#ifndef SWIG`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you put the `%ignore` directive before the `%include`...

```
%ignore functionNotToInclude; // note, not the whole signature
%include "header2.h"
```

For more details see ["Simple renaming of specific identifiers"](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn29) in the SWIG 3.0 manual. (Ignoring is considered a special case of renaming.)